# how to check if an actor is inside the trigger but not the player

Tags: game-physics, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to implement a logic where I shoot balls at 9 trash cans to make fall over the edge. I want to check if all the trashcans has fallen over the edge or not.

[This is the level editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkAOQ.jpg) I have the player on one end and the trash bins on the other end. As you can also see on the top, I have an actor class for the cannonballs and also an actor class for the trash can and the trash cans are all placed using that actor calls. the only stuff of code is in the level blueprint to shoot balls on pressing space. the event graphs of the trigger box, trash cans and the cannon balls are empty. The aim is want to achieve is that i shoot 5 balls and the player all the 9 trash cans into oblivion. I logic i was thinking was by placing a trigger box where the trash cans are and using a counter and decrementing it every time 1 trash can leaves the trigger area. I tried few things but still cannot achieve this.